# Apache httpclient: tutorial is broken - how to actually use this library?

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, ide, httpclient

I am using netbeans as an IDE to give you an indication of background.

I am playing around with the Apache httpclient library as in my current app I am having issues with the in built java HTTP connection.

I heard that the apache library was more powerful.

Anyway, the tutorial documentation that comes with the httpclient library on the apache site seems to be flawed:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Net beans gives me issues with this code snippet (copied straight from the tutorial). Forget even the rudimentary URI of localhost, problems that arise with this are:

1. netbeans complains that HttpClient and DefaultHttpClient are incompatible types. The only way I can see around this is to cast with:

   ```
   (HttpClient) new DefaultHttpClient();
   ```
2. Netbeans complains that the `httpclient.execute()` would throw an error because "httpget" here is simply a method and not a "HttpUriRequest".

How can a simple 3 line tutorial be so wrong and how would I actually successfully complete a request if there is so many flaws in this example?

I'm lost, can someone help. There seems to be several different ways, all not entirely what I'm looking for.

I want to be able to take a well-formed URL that I already have in the app in String, and then follow-all redirects. I'm not at all interested in the contents of the response, merely the cookies that it will drop.

Thanks,

Gregory

Comment: Depends, are you using HttpClient 3.x or HttpClient 4.x? Both are incompatible.

Comment: 4.x downloaded from http://hc.apache.org/ and following tutorial from http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/pdf/httpclient-tutorial.pdf

Comment: i see in documentation that DefaultHttpClient extends AbstractHttpClient and AbstractHttpClient implements HttpClient Interface --> it must work -> please provide imported packages or check it once more .. netbeans must be importing something bad :)

Comment: see here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html

Comment: Currently importing

import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

netbeans still says DefaultHttpClient and HttpClient are imcompatible types.

I downloaded the JARs and put them in a folder called "lib" in the project folder. In netbeans I then added them to the libraries and dragged the jars into a package. The import seems to be working fine.

Comment: I'm miffed to why someone rated this as a bad question? Thanks very much whoever that was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at your imports. I think NetBeans imported your HttpClient 3.x instead of 4.x. Try correcting your imports.

Comment: Ok, I found some example class files in the download. 
you'll find this interesting - in the comments it says: @since 4.0 and gives this method to implement the connection:

`DefaultHttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost("www.google.com", 80, "http");
            HttpGet req = new HttpGet("/");
            HttpResponse rsp = client1.execute(target, req);`

Comment: However, this code still doesn't work. Netbeans still complains it cannot find a symbol - because DefaultHttpClient doesn't have a method "execute". I think you're right with the imports, but I'm using the JAR files, so I have all the files I need - they all in the class path. Do you think I might be missing dependencies?

Comment: Alright, I give up. Netbeans won't make it run, however I try importing the files. I found some guys Maven project and it seems to work, but I have no idea how to use maven or to transfer what he's done to my project. This seems to have dried up. I guess you were along the right lines with your answer anyway. Thanks for trying...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this code, they seem to use different mechanisms than you do. Taken from [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html). This is for the 3.X version though so it might be that you are using a different version.

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;

import java.io.*;

public class HttpClientTutorial {

  private static String url = "http://www.apache.org/";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create an instance of HttpClient.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // Create a method instance.
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);

    // Provide custom retry handler is necessary
    method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

    try {
      // Execute the method.
      int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

      if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
      }

      // Read the response body.
      byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

      // Deal with the response.
      // Use caution: ensure correct character encoding and is not binary data
      System.out.println(new String(responseBody));

    } catch (HttpException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // Release the connection.
      method.releaseConnection();
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: the version I am using is 4.x downloaded directly from http://hc.apache.org/

and the tutorial here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/pdf/httpclient-tutorial.pdf

It seems completely borked.But thanks for the code snippet, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

When I used this (on Android) I implemented a CustomHttpClient, following the example [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RuN0jb4YASwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA316#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: I downloaded the library straight from apache at http://hc.apache.org/
I'll see if I can follow that, I'd be happy to actually make a connection first.